# Trouble using Basic Authentication in Grails

Tags: authentication, grails, spring-security, basic-authentication

I am using CAS + LDAP with Spring Security for user authentication for a Grails 2.2.3 app. However, I would also like to create a simple API with this application which will require a different authentication method. I would like to use Basic Authentication for this. However, adding `basicAuth` to my `Config.groovy` file is not working, and I am getting this error:

```
authentication.ProviderManager Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider
www.BasicAuthenticationFilter Authentication request for user: grantmc failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderNotFoundException: No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
```

I know I'm using the correct credentials, so I'm not sure what the error is saying exactly or what I need to do to fix it. Does anyone have any ideas?

Here are the settings in resources.groovy:

```
initialDirContextFactory(DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource, "ldap://ldap.company.com:389") {
    userDn = "CN=Admin,OU=Users,DC=company,DC=com"
    password = "password"
}

ldapUserSearch(FilterBasedLdapUserSearch,
               "OU=Users,DC=company,DC=com",
               "employeeId={0}",
               initialDirContextFactory) { }

ldapUserDetailsMapper(MyLdapUserDetailsContextMapper) { }

ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator,
                         initialDirContextFactory,
                         "ou=Groups,OU=Users,DC=company,DC=com") {
    groupRoleAttribute = "cn"
    groupSearchFilter = "member={0}"
    rolePrefix = ""
    searchSubtree = true
    convertToUpperCase = true
    ignorePartialResultException = true
}

userDetailsService(LdapUserDetailsService, ldapUserSearch, ldapAuthoritiesPopulator) {
    userDetailsMapper = ref('ldapUserDetailsMapper')
}
```

And my settings in config.groovy:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.cas.serverUrlPrefix = 'https://cas.company.com/cas'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.cas.loginUri = "/login"
grails.plugins.springsecurity.cas.serviceUrl = "${grails.serverURL}/j_spring_cas_security_check"
grails.plugins.springsecurity.providerNames = ['casAuthenticationProvider']
grails.plugins.springsecurity.defaultTargetUrl = '/'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.alwaysUseDefault = false

grails.plugins.springsecurity.useBasicAuth = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.basic.realmName = "API"
grails.plugins.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
        '/api/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter',
        '/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-basicAuthenticationFilter,-basicExceptionTranslationFilter'
]

grails.plugins.springsecurity.securityConfigType = 'InterceptUrlMap'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
        '/api/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'],
        '/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY']
]
```